# How to build string that needs to be hashed - API Authentication with HMAC

Tags: api, authentication, hash, hmac

What is the best way to combine all GET parameters and values together to form a string that needs to be hashed??

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there's a best way but there are plenty of existing uses of this in the wild. Check out [OAuth 1.0a](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/creating-signature) and [HTTP Signatures](https://payswarm.com/specs/ED/http-signatures/2013-05-04/) for some examples.